# Cannot set compress flag on a file in btrfs

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

I have the following btrfs filesystem on CentOS 7:

```
mount | grep btrfs

/dev/sdc on /everything type btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=zlib,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
```

When I try to set the compress flag, it fails:

```
# LANG=C chattr +c  /everything/filelists.xml 
chattr: Invalid argument while setting flags on /everything/filelists.xml
```

I'm using this version of btrfs:
`btrfs-progs-4.9.1-1.el7.x86_64`

I see no error in log files.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Does `lsattr /everything/filelists.xml` show anything useful?

Answer (score 3):

Without a bit more context about the filesystem itself, I can't be certain, but I believe the attempt to set the flag is being rejected because it's redundant with the `compress=` mount option.  This isn't standard behavior on any version of BTRFS I know of, but RHEL (and by extension CentOS) uses a really odd kernel which is based off of what is currently an ancient base version with a bunch of newer patches hand-picked and backported, so it's *really* hard to tell exactly what their kernels will do.

Setting the `compress=` or `compress-force=` (and you probably actually want the second one, otherwise BTRFS gives up on compressing files fairly easily) mount options will set the *default* for that volume.  In other words, mounting with `compress=zlib` (like you are) tells BTRFS to ignore the compress flag and just compress all newly written data on that volume.  The only exceptions to this are:

- `compress=none`, which does not ignore the compression flag.
- The `btrfs filesystem defrag` command, which can override the compression for files it's defragmenting (for example, where I work we mount the volume with `compress=none` (so new data isn't compressed), and then run a weekly defrag pass on all files that haven't been modified since the last pass which compresses them in place).